# How can I complete an iPad update when I can't hit "continue"? (broken digitizer)

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

My iPad's digitizer has a few dead areas.  I can live with it.   I just updated iOS using iTunes, and it's saying

```
                   Update completed  
  Your iPad was updated successfully.  There are just a 
     few more steps to follow, and then you're done!

                       Continue
```

..... and, the "continue" button is **right in a dead area** on the digitizer.

Rotating the iPad does nothing; it will only interact in the home-button-down orientation.

I have tried home button, on/off and rebooting.

Is there any way I can access the iPad through iTunes to get through this screen?

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd need to enroll that iPad in a MDM that can push a profile to suppress that setup step. I still believe you'll need to tap something there as well on iOS 11 so you may need to pay to repair the digitizer at this point.

If you had screen zoom accessibility on, you might be able to multi you h your way to zooming and panning that control so it was on part of the digitizer that still works but I don't think that's enabled either during the pre-setup portion of iOS or amenable to set over iTunes and USB/WiFi sync.

Comment: Sorry to hear.  Pricing isn't so bad, and the job's not so bad when the digitizer/glass is a writeoff.

Comment: @Harper Yes and Apple repairs for screens are getting more competitive and I'll actually entertain some third party options when cost is the primary factor over service or longevity of the repair. More so on iPhones, but some iPad repair shops are doing very good work these days.